# check which button has been clicked in javascript when running a php page via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i have a form on a blog post that displays two submit buttons.

One is save and the other is to delete. E.g.:

```
<form class="updatepost">
<input type="submit" name="saveupdatebutton" class="saveupdatebutton" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="deleteupdatebutton" class="deleteupdatebutton" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Currently, i have this for the js:

```
// JavaScript - Edit Post

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".updatepost").submit(function(){
    var $targetForm = $(this);

    $targetForm.find(".error").remove();
    $targetForm.find(".success").remove();

    // If there is anything wrong with 
    // validation we set the check to false
    var check = true;

    // Get the value of the blog update post
    var $ckEditor = $targetForm.find('.ckeditor'),
        blogpost = $ckEditor.val();


            // Validation
    if (blogpost === '') {
        check = false;
       $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('border', 'none');
    }

      // ... goes after Validation
    if (check) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/updatepost.php",
    data: $targetForm.serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

    if (response.databaseSuccess)
       $targetForm.find('.editor').toggle(),
       <!-- Check for .buildtext id etc to prevent it showing any other posts when updating it -->
       $targetForm.find('#'+response.postid+'').load(''+response.pageurl+' #'+response.postid+''),
       $targetForm.find('#'+response.postid+'').toggle(), 
       $targetForm.find('.edity').toggle(),
       $targetForm.find('.saveupdatebutton').toggle(),
       $targetForm.find('.deleteupdatebutton').toggle();
    else
       $ckEditor.after('<div class="error">Something went wrong!</div>');

}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

This obviously runs the code when the form is submitted. But i want to run a different js ajax call depending on what button is clicked.

I have tried this:

```
// JavaScript - Edit Post

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".saveupdatebutton").click(function(){
     DO STUFF ETC...
});
});
```

But that doesnt work. Any help how i can determine which button is clicked and then carry out a different js code.

Comment: Instead of running that code on the submit event, change it to the click event of your .saveupdatebutton element.  Then you can bind your other functionality to the click of the .deleteupdatebutton element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
$(".saveupdatebutton").click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('activeBtn');
});

$(".updatepost").submit(function(){
   var isSave= $(this).find('.saveupdatebutton').is('.activeBtn');

   if( isSave){
       /* save code*/
   }else{
        /* delete code*/
    }

})
```

Comment: Excellent! Never would have thought about it this way but it works a treat :) Just gotta work on the delete ajax call now :) Many thanks!